# how to insert a summation of 2 values in back end in sql database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, winforms

I am trying to Create a stock entry system in C# with SQL database, and i am having a problem with editing an already added item into database. When i adding a stock for an item code when it some pieces available in stock it is replacing the new stock and deleting about old stock quantity. I need a summation of old available quantity and new quantity. I have tried this edit query this is replacing the new value.

```
 string SQLStatement = "Select * from Stock_Entry where Item_Code='" + textBox_ItemId.Text + "'";
            SqlDataReader myreader = DBConnection.viewDetails(SQLStatement);
            if (myreader.Read())
            {
                string SQL = "Update Stock_Entry Set No_of_Items='"
                 + (Convert.ToDecimal(label_avlQty.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(textBox_Stock.Text)) + "', "
               + "Entry_Date='" + dateTimePicker_StkInDat.Text.Trim() + "',"
               + "Unit_Price='" + textBox_UntPrc.Text.Trim() + "',"
               + "Store_Loation='" + textBox_Store.Text.Trim() + "',"
               + "Stock_Location='" + textBox_StlLktn.Text.Trim() + "',"
               + "GRN_No='" + textBox_GRNno.Text.Trim() +
               "' Where Item_Code='" + textBox_ItemId.Text.Trim() + "'";

                DBConnection database = new DBConnection();
                int rslt = database.updatetValues(SQL);
```

Comment: what error occured...

Comment: No errors, but in quantity i need to save total value of Old available quantity in db and new added stock from text box,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
string SQL = "Update Stock_Entry Set No_of_Items= No_of_Items +" + (Convert.ToDecimal(100));
```

and please use parameterized query to avoid SqlInjection and also it helps to make things readable.

Comment: No i have tried this its giving me an error under No_of_Items

Comment: ' string SQL = "Update Stock_Entry Set No_of_Items='" +
                     No_of_Items + (Convert.ToDecimal(textBox_Stock.Text)) + "', "'

Comment: @user3021112 see the updated query and try that and let me know if there is any issue.